# Grouping by into 15mins

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I try to groupby my dataset in sets of 15mins instead of hours. I currently have my yearly data grouped into dayhour 0 to 23, but in order to have more datapoints, I would like to do this for every 15 mins, such that I end up with 00:00,00:15.... 23:45

This is the first part of my inital dataframe `merged`:

```
                     Price  Afnemen  Invoeden  ...  Temperature  Precipation  NWSE
StartTime                                      ...                                
2018-06-13 00:00:00  42.30    34.02     34.02  ...        13.60          0.0     N
2018-06-13 00:15:00  42.30    42.57     42.57  ...        13.60          0.0     N
2018-06-13 00:30:00  42.30    42.02     42.02  ...        13.60          0.0     N
2018-06-13 00:45:00  42.30    46.09     46.09  ...        13.60          0.0     N
```

With this line `merged= merged.groupby(merged.index.hour).mean()`
I get the hourly means

```
 StartTime      Price    Afnemen  ...  Windspeed  Temperature  Precipation
           0  47.163836  47.910985  ...   3.508562     9.591096     0.045890
           1  44.473082  46.274221  ...   3.500000     9.265582     0.041438
           2  42.862123  43.309392  ...   3.445205     8.974658     0.060959
```

However, I would like to get something like:

```
StartTime      Price    Afnemen  ...  Windspeed  Temperature  Precipation
00:00           (Some value here)
00:15
...
23:45
```

I thought about using `merged.groupby(merged.index.hour,merged.index.minute).mean()`
But in this way I would get two index columns. This is not desirable, as the final goal is to plot the datapoints.

I hope, this question is clear and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your index is a `DateTimeIndex` you can use `Grouper`:

```
agg_15m = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).mean()
```

[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: Yes, indeed, the index is `DateTimeIndex`. However, I also tried this, and there was no grouping of the hours. In the end, I still had the same dataframe as in the beginning